# How to load home page after closing the app using jquery mobile,phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

Im working on jquery mobile,phonegap application.It contains a home screen and it navigate to second page on click of a button.

The problem is if i close the application on second page and open it again, it doesnt load the home screen.

I would like to load the home screen always irrespective of wherever i close the application.

Thanks,
Srinivas

Comment: What do you mean by "close it"? And on what platform are you working? By default closed app on Android is not really closed, so if you return to it you will see your last screen.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Iam using android. Now i understood the default closed app will open the last visited page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly your mobile app is put into the background and you want it to show home page when it is brought to the front.

In this case you can use this Phonegap event **[pause](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#pause)**:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", yourCallbackFunction, false);

function yourCallbackFunction() {

}
```

This function will execute when mobile app is but to the background. When this event occurs you only need to change jQM page to your home page, like this:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#some-page");
```

Basically your code would look like this:

```
document.addEventListener("pause", switchPage, false);

function switchPage() {
    $.mobile.changePage("#home-page");
}
```